# How can I assign a submit button's id to a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

First post on Stack, thanks in advance.

I have a webpage that has 8 different forms, and on submit, I would like each one to display a different set of strings that I have stored in JavaScript arrays. The code to display the array works fine when used with only one form on the page, but I can't get it to work with all 8.

I have assigned each submit button an `id`, and am trying to assign that id to a variable called "chosen button" on submit. "chosen button" ultimately corresponds to the appropriate array, but only if the id is assigned to the variable. Here is html code:

```
<form id="ipsum-form" action="#" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="button" id="corporate" value="And So Forth.." />
```

And Javascript (my array variables and switch statement are obviously much longer):

```
var chosen_button = $("#ipsum-form submit").id;
var corporateIpsum = ["corporate jargon", "etc etc"];
switch (chosen_button){
  case "corporate":
  words = corporateIpsum;
  break;
}
```

Is this the correct way to assign the submit button's ID to the variable? If not (or if this doesn't work for what I want), how can I make this work?

Cheers and I look forward to posting and learning more here in the future.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to go about this is to use onclick callbacks for each of your submit buttons...  Also, you don't appear to be doing anything with your form, so why are you using submit buttons instead of just <button> elements and ditch the form all together?

Comment: I omitted the body of the form to save space. i don't disagree that onclick callbacks might work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `var chosen_button = $('#ipsum-form .button').attr('id');`. You can also use handlers to get the object (more useful in some situations) ex:

```
$('#ipsum-form input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
  var chosen_button = $(this).attr('id');
  // more code.
});
```

**EDIT:** Little bit more correct.

Comment: You beat me to it. Only issue I see here is that you will have to `preventDefault()` on the click event or the form will submit. Even better would be to use just a `button` instead of a `submit`.

Comment: True, depending on the expected end result `.preventDefault()` and button would work better.

Comment: I'm just using `return false;` to prevent the form from submitting

Answer (score 2):

easy:

```
var chosen_button = $("#ipsum-form [type='submit']")[0].id;
```

or plain js:

```
document.forms[0].querySelectorAll('input[type="submit"]')[0].id;
```

Comment: Because the jQuery selector gives you a collection, so you have to pick an element in it to access javascript properties. Or else : `$("#ipsum-form .button").attr("id");`